# problem loading values to my extjs grid using json

Tags: json, extjs, struts

I am loading the values coming from database via a json object using java struts, 
but the values are not populating in my extjs grid: I keep getting an empty grid.

I have included my code below.

**home.jsp**

A button will be there on this page. On clicking the getvalues.jsp should come. 
In getvalues.jsp an extgrid should be presen with the content coming from database

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="getvalues.do">
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my Java code. I am populating a JSON object with the values from my database.

```
public class Json extends Action {
    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Employee> emp=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Myservice serve=new Myservice();
        emp=serve.getemployeesservice();
        Iterator<Employee> empitr=emp.iterator();
        JSONArray json=new JSONArray();
        JSONObject JSONobj=new JSONObject();
        while(empitr.hasNext()){
            JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject();
            Employee empl=new Employee();
            empl=empitr.next();
            jobj.put("empid",empl.getEmpid());
            jobj.put("empname",empl.getEmpname());
            json.add(jobj);
        }
        JSONobj.put("employee",json);
        System.out.println(JSONobj.toString());
        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
}
```

**getvalues.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ext-all.css"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-base.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function() {
            var store=new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                proxy:new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                    url:'http://localhost:8080/JsonExample/getvalues.do'
                }),
                reader:new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                    root:'employee',
                    fields:['empid','empname']
                })
            });

            store.load();
            var recs=store.getRange();
            alert(recs.length);

            var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                title:'employee information',
                columns: [{
                   header:"employeeid",
                   width:100,
                   dataIndex:'empid',
                   sortable:true
                },{ 
                    header:"employeename",
                    width:100,
                    dataIndex:'empname',
                    sortable:true
                }],
                store: store,
                width:300,
                height:300,
                renderTo:Ext.getBody()
            }); 
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        hi
    </body>
</html>
```

But the values are not being populated for some reason. Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you edit your question according to the [formatting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), then i'll take a look at it. Now it's a total mess

Comment: I think you have a typo problem: what is "storetore" in the above js code? Also, what is the error that you get? did you try debugging using firebug? are you receiving any json when you call the load method?

Comment: Indeed fix the formatting, the question looks horrible. Also you have a typo (in Javascript) with "coloumns". Finally, what response text exactly are you receiving in your browser from http://localhost:8080/JsonExample/getvalues.do ?

Comment: Yes... more importantly, what does the JSON being returned by your service look like?  Is it properly formatted?  If you're not using the firefox extention FireBug, you're working without a big toolset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at Java. But, I suspect, your JSON list is not sent to client, you are just printing, but not including it in response.